# PostgreSQL Inserted rows differ from select

Tags: database, postgresql, select, sql-insert

I have a problem with an INSERT in PostgreSQL. I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO track_segments(tid, gdid1, gdid2, distance, speed)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pga.gdid) 
pga.tid as ntid,
pga.gdid as gdid1, pgb.gdid as gdid2,
ST_Distance(pga.geopoint, pgb.geopoint) AS segdist, 
(ST_Distance(pga.geopoint, pgb.geopoint) / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (pgb.timestamp - pga.timestamp + interval '0.1 second'))) as speed
FROM fl_pure_geodata AS pga
LEFT OUTER JOIN fl_pure_geodata AS pgb ON (pga.timestamp < pgb.timestamp AND pga.tid = pgb.tid) 
ORDER BY pga.gdid ASC) AS sq
WHERE sq.gdid2 IS NOT NULL;
```

to fill a table with pairwise connected segements of geopoints. When I run the SELECT alone I get the correct pairs, but when I use it in the statement above, then some are paired the wrong way or not at all. Here's what I mean:

result of SELECT alone:

```
tid;gdid1;gdid2;distance;speed
"0f6fd522-5f1e-49a4-b85e-50f11ef7f908";10;11;34.105058803;31.0045989118182
"0f6fd522-5f1e-49a4-b85e-50f11ef7f908";11;12;90.099603143;14.7704267447541
"0f6fd522-5f1e-49a4-b85e-50f11ef7f908";12;13;23.331326565;21.2102968772727
```

result after INSERT with the same SELECT:

```
tid;gdid1;gdid2;distance;speed
"0f6fd522-5f1e-49a4-b85e-50f11ef7f908";10;12;122.574;17.2639603638028
"0f6fd522-5f1e-49a4-b85e-50f11ef7f908";11;12;90.0996;14.7704267447541
"0f6fd522-5f1e-49a4-b85e-50f11ef7f908";12;13;23.3313;21.2102968772727
```

What be the cause of that? It's exactly the same SELECT statement for the INSERT, so why does it give different results?

Comment: BTW: the `WHERE sq.gdid2 IS NOT NULL;` effectively transforms the LEFT join into a plain join.

Comment: Note 2: the `(pga.timestamp < pgb.timestamp AND pga.tid = pgb.tid)` join condition produces an (N*(N-1)/2) sized (*partial*) carthesian produkt per tid. Is that what you want?

Comment: @joop oh, that's right. I initially wanted to have the nulls displayed, to see if the last point correctly doesn't connect to the next one with different tid. It was kinda late when I wrote that, forgot about the JOINs. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON (pga.gdid)` can pick *any* row from a set with equal `pga.gdid`. You can get different result even by execution the same query for several times. Add additional ordering to get consistent results. something like: `pga.gdid ASC, pgb.gdid ASC`

BTW You may want to order by `pga.gdid ASC, pgb.timestamp - pga.timestamp ASC` to get the "next" point.

BTW2 It may be easier to use `lead()` or `lag()` window functions to calculate differences between current row and next/previous. This way you wont need a self join and will likely get better performance.

Comment: ah, yeah! That makes sense, I hope it works. The old query took 5 seconds, now with the additional order it's already at 2min and counting...

Comment: "getting correct result" often takes more time than "getting some result".

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht see my edit for a possible way to get better performance.

Comment: Just tested with lead()... and holy crap, it only takes 0.3% of the time the original query took.

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering your query results only by the column pga.gdid, which is the same in all the rows, so postgres will order the results in a different way each time you do the select query.

Comment: what do you mean? The gdid are sequential, the first column is the tid, the second and third columns are the gdids

Comment: about your edit: I'm not ordering by the pga.tid though.

Comment: Sorry, im at the phone. I mean that if you order by one column and you have múltiple results with the same value the order of the results is going to be different each time.

Comment: ah, I see, I have to order by pgb.gdid as well to make it work properly. Alright thanks!